# Custom User registration system

Tags: php, user-registration, sql

before asking this question I have been checking out other questions but still could find an answer. Please don't mind if I ask a silly question.

The situation:
I would like to build a user registration system (which user can login and edit their info) in my website. Currently I am just using a custom form the use POST method to store the data in MySQL database (https://gttutor.com/tutor-registration/) [sorry its in Chinese but just wanna show it's a form]. Then I can retrieve the SQL data and show it in a filter (https://gttutor.com/tutor-list/).

I have checked out some plugin like User registration. Yes it can help me create a user in Wordpress easily, but what I want is not the pre-set subscriber or others roles in Wordpress, I want to create a tutor user. And the worst parts is I could not figure out how to combine the wp-user info in database as if they are store in a different format.

To summarize, may I know is it possible to build an external user system (out of the wordpress user registration system) to complete the login and edit profile function. If so, would there be any guidance on it? Hope it is not too vague for the question.

Comment: You can make a new role tutor if that's what you need? You can probably use an external database for authentication and user properties with the right hooks but it might be easier to try not to fight against WordPress like that. When you say "I could not figure out how to combine the wp-user info" what specifically were you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @Rup for your reply! What I mean that is like I could not store custom info like tutor subject or tutor location using pre-set Wordpress registration form as I cannot edit the field freely like a custom form.

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/build-php-mysql-login-and-user-authentication-system/ I am currently following this tutorial to build an external user registration system. Is it possible to work on Wordpress?